# How to use the CKEditor in an custom ASPX page?

Tags: ckeditor

I would like to use the [CKEditor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor) on a [SharePoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint) 2010 Custom Application Page (.aspx).

Is this possible?

Is there an example?

I have no special requirement on a sample. I would like to see only how to place an ASPX Textbox (Multiline) on an aspx page, place the CKEditor on the page and and activate the CKEditor on the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You have to create a plugin with a custom button in it and the open on click a new window (the .aspx page). In this page you have to find the [CKEditor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor) instance, and you are then able to write back HTML to the editor.